# Auto acceleration Kawasaki rouser 135LS

Tags: engine, motorcycle, repair

After starting my motor it’s auto acceleration for a while and then it came to back to normal after
That only I can ride
Is that any problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most engines have an automatic idle (used to be manual using the choke) that gives you higher revs until engine/oil temps have warmed up a bit, by providing a little more fuel and air to the engine. It makes it easier to start and helps prevent stalling.

So it shouldn't be a worry. Unless your bike didn't used to do this and has only just started?